# Saving JSON data to Database Rails from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a url which has been supplied which data is updated every 30 mins and wondering if i can save the data to my database as it updates? I'm using Rails 4.2.0.

There a 10 url's all up, each with a different unit number, which needs to be reference to be able to call each data for each unit.

URL structure

```
http://sitename/cgi-bin/site=1
```

JSON structure

```
{"status"=>"ok", "data"=>[{"2014-08-11 11:00:00"=>14.9},{"2014-08-11 11:30:00"=>15.1}]}
```

Comment: for each element in data you want  a new record?

Comment: Yes. So i'm guessing creation of table: date|number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your json response, it can be done with something like this:

```
json = JSON.parse('{"status"=>"ok", "data"=>[{"2014-08-11 11:00:00"=>14.9},{"2014-08-11 11:30:00"=>15.1}]}') #string representing your json

json['data'].each do |element|
  element.each do |key, value|
    Model.create(date: key, number: value) # This Model is the name of your model
  end
end
```

If you let me suggest you something, You can send json as:

```
{"status"=>"ok", "data"=>[{"date" => "2014-08-11 11:00:00", "number" =>14.9},{...}]}
```

So you can access data like: `element['date']` and `element['number']`

Comment: Great. One more question though. As this is supplied in the format I stated, there are 10 urls each with a different 'unit number' in the url. I have updated what it looks like above, how could this be integrated in say a unit_id column?

Comment: @DollarChills You have to access to site in your `params` hash, I think you can with `params[:site]`, can you post your logger information for a single request?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for crone jobs. Refer this [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and deploying cron jobs and you would save your data on every 30 mins into the database.