# Save each JSON object to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to save each JSON object within the call to a model so I don't have to call the API every single time I load up the application, instead I call all the models entries.

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects'

  # GET /feeds
  # GET /feeds.json
  def boom
    response = self.class.get("/tVv8nTahbhgkyIUW8ByCe0-7/last_ready_run/data?&format=json")
    @elements = response.parsed_response["image"]
    @parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['url'] }
  end
```

This is what I currently have within my model, which perfectly calls the API and displays each one of them within my view. Obviously this isn't the greatest way of doing this, I would like to save each of the JSON's URL property to my model - not entirely sure how to go about doing this!

Comment: Are you using Postgres for your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, it seems you want create a new instance for each value in the response JSON object.

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects'

  has_many :image_urls

  def fetch_image_urls
    response = self.class.get("/tVv8nTahbhgkyIUW8ByCe0-7/last_ready_run/data?&format=json")
    @elements = response.parsed_response["image"]

    @elements.map do |image_info|
      self.image_urls.create(url: image_info['url'])
    end
  end
end


class ImageUrl < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feed

  # add_colum(:image_urls, :url, :string)
end
```

Then, to use this new method...

```
feed = Feed.find(id)
feed.image_urls # => []
feed.fetch_image_urls # => [<ImageUrl url:http://example.com>, ...]
feed.image_urls # => [<ImageUrl url:http://example.com>, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres (which I wouldn't recommend), you can store the hash (instead of JSON) in an HStore column. This will allow you to save all the JSON in one field. You don't have a name for this in you code, so let's call it `info`.

To access the info, you can to define methods.

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  def image
    @info[:image]
  end

  def url
    @info[:url]
  end
```

To save the info,

```
def boom
  ...
  @parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['url'] }
  @info = @parsed
  save
end
```

[HStore reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html)

If you have an Image model with a field name that you want to create,

```
def boom
  ...
  @elements = response.parsed_response["image"]
  @image_urls = @elements.collect { |e| e['url'] }

  @image_urls.each do |url|
    Image.create(url:url)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering in such detail, but I was thinking more along the lines of these two answers, I've seen a few people say Postgres hash storing is a bad way to do this. 

Similar to these
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471957/saving-json-data-to-database-rails-from-url

Comment: If you know what the fields are going to be (such as date and number), then a model might be better. HStore is great if you don't know what the fields are.

Comment: We will always know the fields from the service we're calling from. Would you be able to update your answer with a simple JSON save with a model? e.g. save each image url into a new entry?

Answer (score 0):

You can save whole JSON in a field of model/table and then can get same JSON by `JSON.parse` method.

Comment: Not too sure if this is an answer? I'm looking to map I think to my database.

Comment: You want to map each attribute of the whole json object?

Comment: Yep - e.g. 'name' in JSON to 'name' in my model table